# GoogleTest fails to run with 0xc0000135 when building with CMake under "WindowsStore" (UWP)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, uwp, cmake, googletest

I'm trying to add gtest to an existing UWP project that is being built by CMake.

The build process seems fine and I'm able to create and build the project using:

```
cmake ../ -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -T v141 -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0.14393.0 -Dgtest_disable_pthreads=ON -DCMAKE_USE_WIN32_THREADS_INIT=ON
```

However when I run the test I get:

```
E:\Test-Gtest\build>ctest -C Debug
Test project E:/Test-Gtest/build
    Start 1: example_test
1/1 Test #1: example_test .....................Exit code 0xc0000135
***Exception:   0.03 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.05 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - example_test (Exit code 0xc0000135
)
Errors while running CTest
```

Trying to run the executable example.exe results in:

```
VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll was not found
```

followed by

```
MSVCP140D_APP.dll was not found
```

This is a link to a [MCVE](https://github.com/sgr-ms/TestGtest) on github for convenience which has the following structure (mostly based on the [guidelines in the docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project)):

---

```
│   CMakeLists.txt
│
└───src-test
    │   CMakeLists.txt
    │   CMakeLists.txt.in
    │
    └───src-integration
            basic_logon.cpp
```

main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(TestGtest CXX C)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(src-test)
```

src-test CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)


# Add googletest directly to our build. This defines
# the gtest and gtest_main targets.
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# Now simply link against gtest or gtest_main as needed. Eg

message(STATUS "CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")

file(GLOB SRC_TEST_INTEGRATION_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src-integration/*.cpp)
add_executable(example ${SRC_TEST_INTEGRATION_FILES})
target_link_libraries(example gtest_main)
add_test(NAME example_test COMMAND example)
```

CMakeLists.txt.in

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG           release-1.8.1
  SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
  BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

basic_logon.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <cmath>

TEST(Pow, Two)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(4, std::pow(2,2));    
}
```

Comment: [mcve] should be included in your post, not as a link.

Comment: It's just that it's rather long but I guess there's not better way of doing that :)

Comment: Anyways required here, sorry.

Comment: @VTT the library assumes UWP environment, what do you meant by "regular test application" and it seems that it works for some people unless I'm missing something https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/758

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ updated with the full content

Comment: @Scis Hello I have a similar problem but with a different project. Did you manage to solve the problem? Thanks